# Delete row from Radgrid and refresh page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, postback, radgrid

I have looked all over SO for an answer, but my case seems to be a bit different than the ones posted. I have a Radgrid (Shopping Cart) on my form along with other components (order summary, for example). I want to be able to delete a row from the radgrid and refresh order summary.

What I have tried so far:

1. Used Radgrid's ItemCommand with a button to delete row. This deletes
   the row just fine but does not refresh order summary.
2. Used a button's 'onclick' property to delete row and refresh order summary. This does not actually save the updated radgrid (with
   the row removed).
3. Implemented Step 1 with a LinkButton. Same issue.
4. Used a button's onclick property to then call ItemCommand and delete the row. This deletes the row but does not refresh summary.

I am fairly new to VB, and what I think is happening is when row is deleted using ItemCommand, it's updating the radgrid, but the form is not submitting. Shouldn't button_onclick handle that?

What am I doing wrong? Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" OnClick="lnkRemove_Click" OnCommand="CommandEventHandler" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
```

And here's my codebehind:

```
        Protected Sub lnkRemove_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
          RefreshGrid() 'Refreshes shopping cart grid
          OrderSummary.Refresh() 'Not working           
        End Sub

        Protected Sub CommandEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
          Dim e1 As GridCommandEventArgs = TryCast(e, GridCommandEventArgs)
          If Not e1 Is Nothing Then
            grdMain_ItemCommand(sender, e1)
          End If
        End Sub

        Protected Sub grdMain_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridCommandEventArgs) Handles grdMain.ItemCommand
          Dim table As DataTable = CType(ViewState("dtCart"), DataTable)
          If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
            Dim index As Integer = e.Item.ItemIndex
            table.Rows(index).Delete()
            'more code to remove item(s) from radgrid
        End Sub
```

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding another button 'Update Order' on the form that then posts the page back to the server and order summary gets refreshed. I was making this way more complicated than it should've been.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some code so maybe I can help for you. Because If you write down that have you done it's not helping maybe you did good just you missed a part from the code